# My license.key file missing. How do I transfer the license to other servers?

Tags: config

I just purchased a license from the CP of my production server. Then I went to the config directory to retrieve the license.key for my local dev server but it was not there. I can't find it anywhere. I installed the site the other day using Craft-2.1.2563 and when I went back to look at the zip I see that the license file is missing there as well.

What do I do? How can I transfer the license to my dev environment as well?

FYI - I set up my dev environment a few weeks ago and it was based on a slightly older build of Craft 2 - I'm not sure which version. But, it does have a license.key file. That doesn't do me any good because I purchased a license on the production server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The Craft .zip does not come with the license.key file. From the Craft docs: "It doesn’t get one until you have finished installing Craft and it has made its first call to our web service to check for updates."

Make sure your Craft edition upgrade went through, it seems a bit odd that you upgraded editions and you don't have a license.key file.

Double check that it's not there (craft/config/license.key), maybe by using a search tool on the whole Craft install.

Also try checking for Craft updates to see if that triggers the generation of a license.key file. Restarting the server may help, but you did say it was a production server so that might not be convenient.

If all else fails, I'm sure if you contact P&T ([support@buildwithcraft.com](http://mailto:support@buildwithcraft.com)) they can sort it out.

Comment: Everything Simon said here is spot on... Also, don't forget to change the permissions of your "config" folder (to 755, or something along those lines). That folder only needs to be writable in the beginning, so Craft can create a license key file there. Once the license key has been created, you can change the permissions back.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble with the sever around the time I first installed Craft. That might have prevented it from calling the web service. I just checked and the file is there now. So, either Transmit didn't update the view into that directory (which I think I restarted anyway), or the file was added in the last couple hours after my server successfully called home.